# How do you remove elements added with .add() function in HighCharts?

Tags: highcharts

I have added labels and other graphic on my chart, but I would like to remove them at will.

For example; in a button I make a circle with

```
chart.rendered.circle(100,100,10).attr ({
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    'stroke-width': 1
    )}.add();
```

Now I would like to remove it in another button; but I can't see in the API doc, how you do that.
There is a destroy(), but how do you reference to that circle? I don't see the ID property in the circle object; so I can't address to it like I would do with RemovePlotLine() for example.

I have the same problem for labels too; how do you actually remove items once you create them?

EDIT:

Found a way, which is a bit of a hack: I create the circle as variable, outside the button code; and i hide it right after using add(). Then I use show() and hide() in the button.

```
var mySuperDot= chart.rendered.circle(100,100,10).attr ({
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    'stroke-width': 1
    )}.add()
    .hide();
```

in the button; to show or hide:

```
mySuperDot.show();
mySuperDot.hide();
```

The issue is that this means to add a bunch of variables, while I was trying to put everything inside the button that does the show/hide functionality (I know that this is not portable and good OOP design, I am exploring various options).

Is there a better way to do so?

Second EDIT:

I am new and can't nmake JSFiddle to work :( this is what I did:

- Grab the very first example on the Highcharts site
- Add a button to the web page, call it show (can't paste the html here because the site parse it)
- Add the label code and the button click code:

  $button=$('#show');
  $button.click(function(){

  var extremes=chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes();
  chart.renderer.label(
      'Max Value: '+extremes.dataMax +'
  '+
      'Min Value: '+extremes.dataMax +'
  '+
      'Delta from Goal: '+'
  ',
      1050,
      10
  )
  .attr({fill: 'grey', zIndex: 8})
  .add();
  }

If I want to use the button to toggle that label, I have no way to refer to that label, and remove it. 
If I declare it as variable outside the click code, I can't get the values for getExtremes, and I can remove the label simply using show/hide.

Comment: You have found proper solution - you need a reference to object if you want to hide/show it. Of course, you can add ID to rendered element, then use e.g. `$("#id").hide()`, but still you will need to store that ID somewhere..

Comment: I see, so that's the only way basically to do so. As side note; this works for graphic elements, but if you use a label that show data, it won't work. If I get data in the label (like in the case for getExtremes()), then it won't work (it will print null values if the label is declared outside the button).So if I create a label to serve data from getExtremes() in a button' I have no way to remove it/hide it, basically

Comment: I'm a little confused, could you show jsFiddle example?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to put everything in JSFiddle but I can't make it work; added more details to the main question to show what I did.

Comment: Even though a link to the broken fiddle will also help !

Comment: Try my solution from the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$button = $('#show');
var label; 
$button.click(function () {

    var extremes = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes();
    label = chart.renderer.label('Max Value: ' + extremes.dataMax + '
        ' + 'Min Value: ' + extremes.dataMax + '
        ' + 'Delta from Goal: ' + '
        ', 1050, 10).attr({
            fill: 'grey',
            zIndex: 8
    }).add();
}
```

Now you have reference to `label`, so you can call whenever you want `label.hide()/label.show()`.

Comment: I see; but in this way, isn't the label variable set to null and de-referenced, once the button click function end? I thought that variables exist only in the container where they are created, unless are global (I am pretty new to JS; other languages works in this way). Trying this today. Thanks!

Comment: It's long story, but you have created variable, then you have assigned  (without `var`), it should be assigned to the defined global variable (or outer scope). Well, you need to read about variables scope in JS :)

Comment: Will do :) I barely touched JS a couple of decades ago; never imagined that it would be useful to me one day :)